# What's the web framework to use on a front-end web application?

Tags: web-development, web-applications, jquery, web-framework

What do you consider a good client web framework to use on interface business application? jQuery? YUI!? Another? Some plugins useful?

The application will be use mostly internally replacing a desktop application for data entry and lots of queries/views.

Comment: You're looking for a purely client side framework?

Comment: @karianna: Basically yes, but a good solution is always welcome.

Comment: Can I ask why you are using a client side library? Have you considered a RIA framework like Vaadin or Echo? They tend to be much more well suited for "desktop application" replacements than traditional web development (which is great for sites, but not rich apps).

Comment: @Matt: It's a thing to be studied but the back-end is already done.

Answer (score 11):

For my money, you can't beat jQuery. It makes working with JavaScript just that much easier. The out-of-the-box GUI side of things is limited, but there are lots of 3rd party extensions for grids and such that may be of help for your views.

Answer (score 7):

Here are some useful libraries:

- [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and plugins
- [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/), a lot of things you may thought of implementing yourself
- [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/), implements the language core that's missing in JS 1.5
- [RequireJs](http://requirejs.org/), a library management system for JS

There's also [Dojo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojo_Toolkit) framework there, which basically makes you program in JS like it's a desktop GUI application, but I can't say much about it. Watch video presentations on it.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your budget and the the licensing details, but I've always been a big fan of jQuery + ExtJS. jQuery is a fantastic tool for working with the DOM and a simple AJAX Framework, and throwing ExtJS on top of jQuery beings it all together. ExtJS is the best JavaScript UI kit that I've ever worked with. It's fast, never ran into a bug (but it has its quirks), and commercial support is available - if you need it.

ExtJS has a lot of features that a LOB application would benefit from, such as the [desktop](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/desktop/desktop.html) and [charting](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/chart/charts.html). The charts are flash based but its part of the same package.

The fact it is commercial irks some people, but overall it's a well rounded framework that fills a lot of gaps.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone has their own choices but my choice is Dojo.It is just too good and takes away a lot of your headaches. But yes if you are looking for all those third party extensions and stuff, then jQuery might be better for you, and yes jQuery definitely has a larger community than dojo , but believe me that wont hurt much.

Dojo might be a lot confusing in the beginning but it is worth the time you spend on it.

Answer (score 2):

To make a clientside replacement of an old "Winform style" driven backoffice applications Sencha (EXTJS) has been proven to be a really good option.